# How to create application for Android P2P screen sharing?

Tags: android, screen, sharing

I am going to build an application that enable recipients able to see what I am doing (example: typing documents, drawing, etc). For the sender I plan to use an android device (for instance,  Tablet). For the receiver, I will also use Android Device. There can be many recipients.

What are the approaches that I should use? I appreciate for any help/guide/docs. Code samples would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the contents of the screen is not possible in Android, except perhaps via rooted devices and/or custom firmware.

Comment: What it means here is that , when the one/many recepients connected(TCP network) and successfully remote to Server, the recepients will be able to see server is doing one kind of job such as drawing, etc (Desktop Sharing).

Comment: @weiliangchen: That does not change the answer, unless instead of "desktop sharing" you mean "I am going to create a dedicated drawing app that has this mirroring capability". That is at least technically possible, though challenging.

Comment: yes, it is Desktop sharing i mean. is there any reference to create that dedicated drawing application ? does it has to go through Remoting process ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about the specifics, but just use the source from Skype for Android. It's basically the same principle, except, instead of an external camera to capture your face, it'd have to be an internal/emulated one to capture the screen.

Comment: Provide links for your references and make sure they exist and are not based on your assumptions.